# How to fix "SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token @import"?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to add Jest and Enzyme to a React webpack project.

Everything is working, until I add tests to a component, with a style sheet importing google fonts.

The error I get is:

```
● Test suite failed to run
    /Users/dev/Code/Git/react-redux-webpack/src/App.sass:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow+Condensed')
                                                                                             ^
    SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

The sass file looks like:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow+Condensed')

body
    background: #f9f9f9
    color: #444444
    font-family: 'Barlow Condensed', sans-serif
    text-align: center

.container
    width: 100%
    max-width: 960px
    margin: 0 auto

.container__logo--image
    position: absolute
    top: 50%
    left: 50%
    margin-left: -75px
    margin-top: -75px
```

My .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react",
    "stage-0",
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "6.10",
          "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "safari >= 7"]
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties"]
}
```

I have all the required loaders in webpack, I can build and serve the sass all day with no issues. It is the introduction of Jest I am struggling with.

I have pushed a branch with the current state of code here https://github.com/nombienombie/react-redux-webpack/tree/feature/jest-unit-tests

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I added the following to my package.json:

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|sass)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
  },
```

and added the following in a **mocks** folder:

**fileMock.js**

```
module.exports = 'test-file-stub';
```

**styleMock.js**

```
module.exports = {}
```

Comment: how to find the RootDir ?

Answer (score 5):

Since they are not compiled by Webpack, static assets imported by tests should be handled somehow.

The typical approach consists of mocking them out since not relevant for testing purpose. Jest expose a [`moduleNameMapper`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/webpack.html#handling-static-assets) option to easily mock/proxy them.

Answer (score 5):

One more thing to add on the answer given by @Harry,

if you are using `jest.config.js` file  then add on it instead of `package.json`

```js
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$':
      '<rootDir>/src/__mock__/fileMock.js',
    '\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/src/__mock__/styleMock.js',
  },
```